# Wired network randomly stopping, with call trace being logged to syslog

Tags: networking, graphics-card, motherboard

I have a wired connection to a router with XUbuntu 14.04, which works fine right after the computer is booted, but after a couple of minutes it randomly turns off. Here are a couple of thing I've tried to resolve this:

```
1. Disable avahi-daemon
2. Disable IPv6
3. Change IP to static
4. Install latest ethernet drivers (r8168)
```

All this did not help. My network card is built into motherboard:

```
➜  ~  lspci | awk '/net/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many)
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

Now I've noticed that right after disconnect, syslog was appended with this:

```
Sep  8 16:55:14 re-desktop kernel: [  191.242192] r8168: eth0: link up
Sep  8 16:55:14 re-desktop kernel: [  191.242266] sched: RT throttling activated
Sep  8 16:55:16 re-desktop NetworkManager[900]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
Sep  8 16:55:18 re-desktop kernel: [  195.262852] r8168: eth0: link up
Sep  8 16:55:18 re-desktop NetworkManager[900]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469329] irq 19: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469340] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: G           OE  3.19.0-26-generic #28~14.04.1-Ubuntu
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469345] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./970 Extreme4, BIOS P2.20 10/12/2012
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469349]  ffff88042828f2a4 ffff88043ec83e18 ffffffff817aeed7 0000000000000001
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469356]  ffff88042828f200 ffff88043ec83e48 ffffffff810ce576 ffff88043ec8e4c0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469363]  ffff88042828f200 0000000000000013 0000000000000000 ffff88043ec83e98
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469369] Call Trace:
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469372]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff817aeed7>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469391]  [<ffffffff810ce576>] __report_bad_irq+0x36/0xd0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469398]  [<ffffffff810ceaac>] note_interrupt+0x24c/0x2a0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469405]  [<ffffffff814c559a>] ? add_interrupt_randomness+0x3a/0x1e0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469412]  [<ffffffff810cc19e>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0xae/0x1a0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469419]  [<ffffffff810cc2d1>] handle_irq_event+0x41/0x70
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469425]  [<ffffffff810ceed2>] handle_fasteoi_irq+0x82/0x140
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469431]  [<ffffffff81017682>] handle_irq+0x22/0x40
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469437]  [<ffffffff817b9821>] do_IRQ+0x51/0xf0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469444]  [<ffffffff817b762d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469447]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff810ebd13>] ? tick_program_event+0x23/0x30
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469459]  [<ffffffff8105b976>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469466]  [<ffffffff81460cb8>] arch_safe_halt+0x9/0xd
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469471]  [<ffffffff8146158b>] acpi_safe_halt+0x22/0x2b
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469476]  [<ffffffff814615af>] acpi_idle_do_entry+0x1b/0x2b
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469480]  [<ffffffff81461610>] acpi_idle_enter_c1+0x51/0x70
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469487]  [<ffffffff8164feb5>] cpuidle_enter_state+0x55/0x170
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469493]  [<ffffffff81650087>] cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469499]  [<ffffffff810b5404>] cpu_startup_entry+0x334/0x3d0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469506]  [<ffffffff81048cf7>] start_secondary+0x197/0x1c0
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469511] handlers:
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469536] [<ffffffffc01df320>] ahci_single_level_irq_intr [libahci]
Sep  8 16:55:19 re-desktop kernel: [  196.469540] Disabling IRQ #19
```

Which would seem like a hardware failure of my ASRock 970 Extreme4 Motherboard to me.

To add to this, PC started freezing randomly over the last couple of weeks, and sometimes also refusing to even boot to BIOS after a reset. When the computer did not boot, video card fans were very loud, and I tried to unplug one of the monitors (I had 2 monitors connected over DVI), which mostly fixed the freezing issue. This led me to believe video card (`Palit GeForce 260`, which is much older than the rest of the PC) should be replaced, but now I'm not sure.

Is this a hardware issue? Should I replace the motherboard, or can a faulty video card cause this?